# Auto-append to bash script after GitLab Checkin

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, git-bash, continuous-deployment

Community, without going through the process of setting up GitLab CI (Continuous Integration), do any of you know how I may automate a process as described below?

1. After GitLab check-in, have the checked-in filename added to either a text file or update a bash-script that references the full path of the file that was checked in?
2. The bash script would then be used to execute the code in each of the checked-in files.

Bit of background, the files are SQL DDL files needed to build tables/views/packages. I want my DEV team to only worry about updating the DDL, and have a process that automatically builds database objects.

The idea here is to have a bash/perl/ksh whatever file, that calls SQLPLUS and sequentially executes the DDL in each of the files.

To be clear, I already know how to write the BASH code that calls SQLPLUS and iterates over the list of files.. just need a way to automate the filename append, whenever a check-in happens to GitLab.

Welcoming any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of doing this.

## Git Hooks

This is possible using Git Hooks. A *Git Hook* is a function that is executed when certain events occur in the repository. They are either server-side or client-side.

Server-side hooks would execute on GitLab in your case, when someone pushes to the repository, while client-side hooks are executed on the client, e.g. before or after a commit.

In your case, the server-side *post-receive* hook would probably work. Check out one of the tutorials on Git Hooks for more details, e.g. [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/server-side-hooks). You would basically write your script (as you indicated in your question) and then set it up as a *post-receive* hook on the server to execute whenever there are changes in the repo.

## Continuous Integration

While Git Hooks might work for this case, this really sounds like a use case for a *continuous integration* tool like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) or [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo).

These tools are used to trigger a *build* after changes in a repository. A build usually contains things like compiling sources, running unit tests, deploying an application to a server, creating a distributable version of the application, etc.

In your case, you would set up a build plan that does what you describe in your question (pulling in the changes, updating the text file, running the database scripts, ...).

Based on my experience, I suggest you look into a continuous integration system. This is the standard way of doing things like you're asking, and you will find that there's other things you want to do when someone commits. Having a standardized process like CI in place will help a lot.

Git Hooks might work for this, but are harder to maintain and less flexible.